# RuntimeError: cannot import name 'ORTModelForSequenceClassification' from 'optimum.onnxruntime' (Windows 10)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to quantization hugging face model with cpu but getting the error on importing ORTModelForSequenceClassification. I have searched a lot but I am unable to find solution. I have tried on different computer just to be sure it's not something with my computer but it still producing the same error.

Error:
RuntimeError: Failed to import optimum.onnxruntime.modeling_ort because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'ORTModelForSequenceClassification' from 'optimum.onnxruntime

My code looks like this:

```
import datasets
import evaluate
import transformers

task_type = "text-classification"

model_id = "juliensimon/distilbert-amazon-shoe-reviews"

dataset_id = "juliensimon/amazon-shoe-reviews"
label_column = "labels"
label_mapping = {
    "LABEL_0": 0,
    "LABEL_1": 1,
    "LABEL_2": 2,
    "LABEL_3": 3,
    "LABEL_4": 4,
}

data = datasets.load_dataset(dataset_id, split="test")
print(data)
metric = evaluate.load("accuracy")
evaluator = evaluate.evaluator(task_type)


def evaluate_pipeline(pipeline):
    results = evaluator.compute(
        model_or_pipeline=pipeline,
        data=data,
        metric=metric,
        label_column=label_column,
        label_mapping=label_mapping,
    )
    return results


print("*** Original model")
classifier = transformers.pipeline(task_type, model_id)
results = evaluate_pipeline(classifier)
print(results)

print("*** ONNX")

from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTModelForSequenceClassification #This line throws error
# from optimum.onnxruntime.modeling_ort import ORTModelForSequenceClassification #Also tried importing through this but it give circular import error
from optimum.pipelines import pipeline

model = ORTModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    model_id, from_transformers=True
)
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model.save_pretrained("./model_onnx")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("./model_onnx")
classifier_onnx = pipeline(task_type, model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
results = evaluate_pipeline(classifier_onnx)
print(results)

print("*** ONNX optimizer")

from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTOptimizer
from optimum.onnxruntime.configuration import OptimizationConfig

optimizer = ORTOptimizer.from_pretrained(model)
optimizer.optimize(
    OptimizationConfig(
        optimization_level=99, # 1, 2 or 99
    ),
    save_dir="./model_onnx",
)
model_optimized = ORTModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "./model_onnx", file_name="model_optimized.onnx"
)
classifier_optimized = pipeline(task_type, model=model_optimized, tokenizer=tokenizer)
results = evaluate_pipeline(classifier_optimized)
print(results)

print("*** ONNX quantizer")

from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTQuantizer
from optimum.onnxruntime.configuration import AutoQuantizationConfig

quantizer = ORTQuantizer.from_pretrained(model)
qconfig = AutoQuantizationConfig.avx512_vnni(is_static=False, per_channel=True)
quantizer.quantize(save_dir="./model_onnx", quantization_config=qconfig)
model_quantized = ORTModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "./model_onnx", file_name="model_quantized.onnx"
)
classifier_quantized = pipeline(task_type, model=model_quantized, tokenizer=tokenizer)
results = evaluate_pipeline(classifier_quantized)
print(results)
```

The Packages in Virtual Enviornment looks like this:
aiohttp            3.8.4
aiosignal          1.3.1
async-timeout      4.0.2
attrs              23.1.0
certifi            2023.5.7
charset-normalizer 3.1.0
colorama           0.4.6
coloredlogs        15.0.1
datasets           2.12.0
dill               0.3.6
evaluate           0.4.0
filelock           3.12.0
flatbuffers        23.5.26
frozenlist         1.3.3
fsspec             2023.5.0
huggingface-hub    0.15.1
humanfriendly      10.0
idna               3.4
joblib             1.2.0
mpmath             1.3.0
multidict          6.0.4
multiprocess       0.70.14
numpy              1.24.3
onnx               1.12.0
onnxruntime        1.15.0
optimum            1.4.1
packaging          23.1
pandas             2.0.2
pip                22.0.4
protobuf           3.20.1
pyarrow            12.0.0
pyreadline3        3.4.1
python-dateutil    2.8.2
pytz               2023.3
PyYAML             6.0
regex              2023.6.3
requests           2.31.0
responses          0.18.0
scikit-learn       1.2.2
scipy              1.10.1
sentencepiece      0.1.99
setuptools         58.1.0
six                1.16.0
sympy              1.12
threadpoolctl      3.1.0
tokenizers         0.12.1
torch              1.13.0+cpu
tqdm               4.65.0
transformers       4.22.1
typing_extensions  4.6.3
tzdata             2023.3
urllib3            2.0.2
xxhash             3.2.0
yarl               1.9.2

Full Error Traceback:

````
  File "D:\Lpython\Article Summarizer\summarize\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 1031, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\singh\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Lpython\Article Summarizer\summarize\lib\site-packages\optimum\onnxruntime\modeling_ort.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .utils import ONNX_WEIGHTS_NAME, get_device_for_provider, get_provider_for_device, parse_device
  File "D:\Lpython\Article Summarizer\summarize\lib\site-packages\optimum\onnxruntime\utils.py", line 21, in <module>
    import onnx
  File "D:\Lpython\Article Summarizer\onnx.py", line 43, in <module>
    from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTModelForSequenceClassification
ImportError: cannot import name 'ORTModelForSequenceClassification' from 'optimum.onnxruntime' (D:\Lpython\Article Summarizer\summarize\lib\site-packages\optimum\onnxruntime\__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Lpython\Article Summarizer\onnx.py", line 43, in <module>
    from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTModelForSequenceClassification
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1055, in _handle_fromlist
  File "D:\Lpython\Article Summarizer\summarize\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 1021, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
  File "D:\Lpython\Article Summarizer\summarize\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 1033, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import optimum.onnxruntime.modeling_ort because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'ORTModelForSequenceClassification' from 'optimum.onnxruntime' (D:\Lpython\Article Summarizer\summarize\lib\site-packages\optimum\onnxruntime\__init__.py)```
````